# Faço comando no Git para clonar repositório mas ele clona apenas as pastas ".git" e ".gitignore"

Tags: git, eclipse, github, clone

Eu faço o comando para clonar o código que está no GitHub mas o Git clona apenas a pasta ".git" e o ".gitignore".

Aqui está o meu repositório:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(Se eu estiver colocando muitas fotos, desculpem-me... sou novo aqui, estou aprendendo rsrs...)

E então eu iniciei o Git na minha pasta de projetos do Eclipse, conforme mostra a imagem a abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E vejam que já fiz a clonagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas vejam que ele não clona o restante dos dados, mas apenas as duas pastas que falei... O que posso ter feito de errado?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço toda ajuda que puderem dar...

Comment: Já tentou a opção `git clone -b master https://github.com/VictorHSM24/aula1-github`

Comment: Utilize `git branch --all` para listar todos os ramos do projeto e `git switch <branch-name>` para alterar entre eles.

Answer (score 2):

O *clone* foi feito corretamente. Tanto que no seu primeiro *print*, mostra só o *.gitignore*, mas no *branch Main*.
Como podemos ver nos seus outros *prints*, você também criou o *branch Master* e foi nela que você subiu seu código fonte.

Na sua máquina local, você precisa fazer o *checkout* dessa *branch* para poder trabalhar nela.

```
git checkout -b master
```

Que aí vai aparecer o certo.
Mas ainda sim, você precisa resolver o problema, da uma olhada nesse vídeo aqui que eu gravei, explicando essa questão dos *branch’s*.

https://youtu.be/e6doXVQxhSU